# Turn off keyboard shortcuts in JetBrains Rubymine

Tags: ruby, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

I know that this is probably very simple, but it's driving me crazy and I cannot work well. Is there a way to completely turn off shortcuts in rubymine? Especially those which cover refactoring like <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. In my set language (czech) I use these shortcuts for things like @ { & and so on... so, thanks for answers

Comment: I'm _fairly_ sure there's a keymap option in the lower pane of the preferences. There you can copy any keymap and remove the mappings you don't want (some, such as backspace, are pretty good to have, so removing them all may not be a great idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> To configure keyboard shortcuts and mouse shortcuts
>
> Open Settings dialog and click Keymap.
> Select one of the pre-configured Keymaps,
> which you want to use as the base for the new one, and click Copy. Accept the default name, or change it as required.
>
> In the content pane
> of actions, select the desired action.
>
> Configure keyboard shortcuts.
> To do that, follow these steps:
>
> Click  properties on the toolbar, or
> right-click the selected action, and choose Add Keyboard Shortcut.
> Enter Keyboard Shortcut dialog box opens.
>
> Press the keys to be used as
> shortcuts. The keystrokes are immediately reflected in the First
> Stroke field. Optionally, select the check box next to Second Stroke
> and press keys to be used as alternative keyboard shortcuts.
>
> As you
> press the keys, the Preview field displays the suggested combination
> of keystrokes, and the Conflicts field displays warnings, if some of
> the keystrokes are already assigned to the other actions.
>
> Click OK
> with the mouse pointer to create a shortcut and bind it with an
> action.

For more info see [the documentation which explains things very well.](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

I think this should work. good luck :)